# Spring 3.2.2 + Tiles3 + i18n not found

Tags: internationalization, spring-3, tiles-3

I have one jsp look that.

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%> 
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>

        <div class="container-fluid">

            <div class="logo row-fluid">

                <div class="span12">

                    <img src="<c:url value="/img/logo.png"/>" />

                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="row-fluid">

                <div class="span6">

                    <form>

                        <fieldset>

                            <legend></legend>

                        </fieldset>

                    </form>

                </div>

                <div class="span6">

                    <form>

                        <fieldset>

                            <legend><spring:message code="home.form.legend.local"/></legend>

                        </fieldset>

                    </form>

                </div>

            </div>

        </div>
```

With `<spring:message />`tag jsp broken with this message: **org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.apache.tiles.request.render.CannotRenderException: ServletException including path '/WEB-INF/jsp/public_layout.jsp'.**

If remove `<spring:message />`tag run without problem.

xxx-servlet.xml config:

```
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesView"/>
</bean>

<bean id="tilesConfigurer" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer">
    <property name="definitions">
        <list>
            <value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

tiles.xml:

```
<tiles-definitions>

    <definition name="public.layout" template="/WEB-INF/jsp/public_layout.jsp">
        <put-attribute name="header" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/header.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name="body" value="" />
        <put-attribute name="footer" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/footer.jsp" />
    </definition>

    <definition name="home" extends="public.layout">
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/home.jsp" />
    </definition>

</tiles-definitions>
```

public_layout.jsp:

```
<%@taglib prefix="tiles" uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>

<tiles:insertAttribute name="header" />

<tiles:insertAttribute name="body" />

<tiles:insertAttribute name="footer" />
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping({"/", "/index"})
public String showHome() {

    return "home";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.apache.tiles.request.render.CannotRenderException: ServletException including path '/WEB-INF/jsp/public_layout.jsp'.

this only says there was an error in public_layout.jsp
there should be another error more specific to the `<spring:message />` failure

Comment: Hi mck, I solved problem using fmt taglib instead spring taglig. Thank you for you interest. ;)